# How to to remove characters from numeric value using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have the value 4,59,999/-. My code is

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(s,@"\b[1-9]\d*(?:,[0-9]+)*/?-?"))
{
    string value = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\d]", " ");
    textBox2.Text= value;
}
```

Output is: 4 59 999, I need it to be 459999 (without ","  ,  "/"  , "-" and " ").

Comment: I suspect a design flaw.  Why is that value a string in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

How about without regex?

```
var s = "4,59,999/-";
var array = s.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray();
```

or shorter

```
var array = s.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray();
```

[image]

And you can use this array in a [`string(Char[])` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var result = new string(array); // 459999
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex, you could use:

```
 textBox2.Text = String.Concat(s.Where(Char.IsDigit));
```

Much better is to use `decimal.Parse`/`TryParse`:

```
string s = "4,59,999/-.";
decimal price;
if (decimal.TryParse(s.Split('/')[0], NumberStyles.Currency, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out price))
    textBox2.Text = price.ToString("G");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace with empty string.

```
string value = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\d]", ""); // See the change in the replace string.
textBox2.Text= value;
```

**Note** You don't require the `if` as the regex replace will work only if there is a match for non digits (`[^\d]`)

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the ",", "/", "-" and " " with a white space. Try this instead:

```
string value = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\d]", "");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `""` is not whitespace.  It is the empty string.

Comment: @phoog Yes but I tries to explain what the OP dix wrong and not what he should do

Comment: Ah, I see.  I have edited your answer slightly to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Should just be a case of replacing it with an empty string instead of a space?

`Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\d]", String.Empty);`

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're replacing these characters with a space. Use an empty set of quotes instead.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(s,@"\b[1-9]\d*(?:,[0-9]+)*/?-?"))
{
    string value = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\d]", "");
    textBox2.Text= value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq is a possible solution:

```
  String s = "4,59,999/-";
  ...
  textBox2.Text = new String(s.Where(item => item >= '0' && item <= '9').ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this it will work 100% in php so just change some syntax for C#

```
<?php
    $str = "4,59,999/-.";
    echo $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/', '', $str);
?>
```